# MongoDB Failed to Convert Int64 to Int32 using $Convert

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to convert all documents in a mongo collection which have a field currently set as Int64 to Int32.

Currently here is my document:

```
{
       _id: ObjectId("60af668346895440fad766c2"),
       userId: 'xxxxxxxx',
       postName: 'testPost',
       numberOfComments: Long("3"),
       numberOfLikes: Long("6")
     }
```

As stated above I would like to change numerbOfComments from a Long (Int64) to Int32

I've tried using multiple ways (see below) but it just changes the data type in the output and does not modify the document on the DB.

Can anyone help please

**What I've tried so far**

```
db.posts.aggregate(
  [
    {
      $project:
        { 
          result:
          {
            $convert: { 
              input: "$numberOfComments",
              to: "int",
              onError: "An error occurred",
              onNull: "Input was null or empty" 
            }
          }
        }
    }
  ]
)
```

I've also tried this:

```
db.posts.aggregate([
      {
        $set: {
          numberOfComments: { toInt: '$numberOfComments' },
        },
      },
    ], {multi: true})
```

```
db.posts.updateMany(
  { numberOfComments : { $type: Long } },
  [{ $set: { numberOfComments: { $toInt: "$numberOfComments" } } }],
  { multi: true })

   db.UserProjects.aggregate(
     [
       {
         $project:
           {
             _id: 0,
             numberOfComments: { $toInt: "$numberOfComments" }
           }
       }
     ]
   ).pretty()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use aggregate update.

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/I3wqoQm1qp1)

```
db.collection.update({
  key: 3 //You can leave empty
},
[ //aggregate update as you need $toInt
  {
    $set: {
      numberOfComments: {
        "$toInt": "$numberOfComments"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

I set an error example in the playground. If you set a valid value, it will work.

Please explore options part to update one/many documents.

Comment: Firstly @Gibbs thank you for the response and your help. If i need to run this against all docs in my collection how would I do that? If I run what you've given me above it just updates 1 doc (I have a few hundred)

Comment: Also where was the syntax error can you tell me? Just trying to learn where I've been going wrong. Thank you again!

Comment: Actually is it just adding? {multi: true}) (seems to have worked)

Comment: My bad, no syntax error. Yes, that's what I meant by options(multi)

Comment: Ah cool! One last question if I may, what was i doing wrong with $Convert...did I misunderstand its purpose? Once again thank you for the answer above and for your time....you saved my sanity  :-d

Comment: No. Your understanding and usage are perfect. You tried to project then you applied that logic in aggregate update. Not all aggregate operations are supported in update aggregate.

Comment: Ah ok I think I get it :-D Thank you once again for your help!! Take care